# NavigationController based app, view is doubled and a ghost image drifts slowly off the right side of the screen

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

This is so weird.  I have been working on a series of iterations of the same application for almost 2 months, have not touched the code related to the view management in weeks, and this bug just appeared.

Basically I am at the root level view, i go to the last view in the stack by way of a "skip" type button.  This page is used for settings.  I then change some things (not related to the view hierarchy) and save, which takes me back to root.  Then i try going to the first view in the stack.

Initially all of the textfields for the view are visible, but their uilabels are not.  The view then slowly drifts to the right, revealing the same view with labels intact directly under it.  I have never seen a bug like this before in over 2 years of iOS dev, so here I am.

The only code I have changed in the last week is related to web services and threading, nothing having to do with the view hierarchy.

If anyone has seen this bug before please help!  Probably important as well, I have not seen this happen on the simulator, only on the actual device (iPad running 4.3.3)

Thanks!

Comment: after two reinstalls the issue has disappeared.... we'll see what happens in the next couple of hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threading is the most likely culprit: making UI calls anywhere other than the main thread can cause any number of strange problems. Make sure anything you do to the UI, even a `-popViewControllerAnimated:`, is wrapped in a `-performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` or an appropriate `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{...})` call.